# Filter docker images by repository name

Tags: docker

Using the command `docker images`, you can list all images on your host:

```
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
scdockerdemo_php             latest              155d80ea7642        4 minutes ago       265.3 MB
scdockerdemo_node            latest              6189bc65c3fe        8 minutes ago       861.4 MB
php                          5.6-apache          fc50bce69ea0        3 days ago          481.3 MB
node                         4.1                 fc81e574af43        3 days ago          641.1 MB
```

With `docker images -f "tag=latest"`, you can filter for images with a certain tag.

How can I filter for a repository name? E.g. `docker images -f "repository=scdockerdemo_*"`

This command always return Invalid filter 'repository'

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/images/

Comment: Getting invalid filter tag - if "tag=<tag>" used

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you want to filter by repository name(eg: testImage), just use the following:

```
docker images testImage
```

When you have multiple images with same repository name but diffetent tags, you can specify tags on the repository name by using a `':'` ( For example, `testImage:<whatever tag>`)

Source: [Docker images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/)

Comment: great answer. This also allows repository to be used as a filter (e.g. powershell docker rmi $(docker images <myRepo>* -q)).

Comment: Usage:  ``docker images [OPTIONS] [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]``

Comment: Precise section of the doc : [List images by name and tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#list-images-by-name-and-tag)

Comment: Good news, you can also use wildcard in tag name, like ``docker images java:8*`` or ``docker images tomcat:7*`` !

Comment: life saver answer !  I used it to clean a certain image without touching the other ones (bash) :  "docker images some-image-name -q | xargs docker rmi -f"

Answer (score 44):

According to the documentation at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/ you can match by wildcard by enclosing in double quotes:

`docker images "scdockerdemo_*"`

** special chars **
when you have special characters like '/' in the repository name, you should escape it to filter by repository name.

ex)

```
> docker images "zirho6\/*"
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
zirho6/aaaa              latest              946bf5cc28fc        2 days ago          997MB
zirho6/bbbb              latest              741a6e368d07        10 days ago         866MB
zirho6/ccc               latest              173b36570522        12 days ago         853MB
zirho6/dddd              latest              e08e5c202e9b        13 days ago         853MB
```

Comment: Changed to use correct command `images` vs `image` and wrapped the repo name + wildcard in double quotes so the wildcard is recognized.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, that if name is similar to "docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash" you need to apply two wildcards: "docker.elastic.co/*/*" because otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 25):

You can filter images by [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filter-images-by-reference) (combination of `name` and `tag`):

```
docker image ls --filter 'reference=scdockerdemo_*'
```

Comment: Important note. If name looks like: "docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash" matching needs to be applied in form: "docker.elastic.co/*/*" because otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

According to [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659756/1728179), the filter option currently only supports "dangling=true".

If you're using Bash, the easiest thing to do is probably:

```
$ docker images | grep scdockerdemo
```

Or, you can try using awk to match on a string in the first column:

```
$ docker images | awk '$1 ~ /scdockerdemo/ { print }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and your answer. It seems that this is currently the only option. But this doesn't work as an argument for docker commands like e.g. docker rmi $(docker images | grep scdockerdemo)

Comment: I've edited my answer - try matching the repository name in the first column with awk. Then you can `docker rmi $(docker images | awk '$1 ~ /scdockerdemo/ { print $3 }')`.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much this is the anwser!

Comment: And if you're using Windows: `docker images | findstr scdockerdemo`

Answer (score 2):

**There is my solution for filter Docker images by name**

1. List all my Docker images

   ```
   $ sudo docker images
   REPOSITORY                               TAG           IMAGE ID       CREATED       
   pay-with-crypto-apis_store-management    latest        fd78ce3a6869   27 minutes ago  
   pay-with-crypto-apis_webhooks            latest        a305d3a8bd5c   28 minutes ago  
   pay-with-crypto-apis_invoices            latest        1ded36a0dfb1   29 minutes ago  
   pay-with-crypto-apis_authentication      latest        73cf83569a45   30 minutes ago  
   pay-with-crypto-apis_gateway             latest        f6a8ccadd645   34 minutes ago  
   node                                     14-alpine     47afee183159   2 months ago    
   node                                     18            e3cb0fb99b7c   2 months ago    
   btcpayserver/btcpayserver                1.5.4         f4a433460739   3 months ago    
   nicolasdorier/nbxplorer                  2.3.26        121100cdb31b   3 months ago    
   saubyk/c-lightning-rest                  0.7.2         7924309b4d7d   3 months ago    
   shahanafarooqui/rtl                      0.12.3        da155f98b998   4 months ago    
   mongo                                    latest        27dd1be4bed1   4 months ago
   ```

2. I wanna to filter by `pay-with-crypto-apis`

   ```
    $ sudo docker images "pay-with-crypto-apis_*"
    REPOSITORY                              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          
    pay-with-crypto-apis_store-management   latest    fd78ce3a6869   26 minutes ago
    pay-with-crypto-apis_webhooks           latest    a305d3a8bd5c   27 minutes ago
    pay-with-crypto-apis_invoices           latest    1ded36a0dfb1   28 minutes ago
    pay-with-crypto-apis_authentication     latest    73cf83569a45   29 minutes ago
    pay-with-crypto-apis_gateway            latest    f6a8ccadd645   33 minutes ago
   ```

Comment: I think the wild card should be sometihng like this ``pay-with-crypto-apis_\/*`` to filter by the repository name as in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44320646/6048237

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Provide another option for reference

> docker images  | ruby -ne ' puts $_ if $_ =~ /harbor/ '