# Is there a way to create a copy of the docker image on the same host?

Tags: linux, docker

I have this requirement where I need to delete old images during the build, but there could be a chance that they are used by some containers in the same host that I cannot stop and remove during build. So i am wondering if there is a way to duplicate an image and use them for the external containers.

I already tried exploring tag or commit, but they seems not to be fitting my need.

Answer (score 1):

The dangling filter will only remove inactive images

```
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

see [How to use docker images filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659300/how-to-use-docker-images-filter)

Comment: If am forcefully overwriting an image, will any container using it continues to work correctly?